# webstorm и неизвестные методы класса в подсказках

Tags: javascript, webstorm

есть файл `main.js` и `inc.js` в одном проекте webstorm

Содержимое `main.js`

```
class A{
    f1(){}
    f2(){}
}

let a = new A;
a.f1();


var b = require('D:\\Dev\\Project\\js\\storm\\inc.js');
b.f1();
```

Содержимое `inc.js`

```
module.exports = {
    f1: function(a,b) {return a+b;},
    f2: function(a,b) {return a-b;}
};
```

методы класса `A`, при обращении к переменной `a` `webstorm` видит и показывает первыми, это ожидаемое поведение, а вот при обращении к переменной `b`, функции из экспортируемого файла покажет только при полном вводе их имени, а если подключаемый файл вообще не в папке с решением, то `webstorm` функций в нем не показывает совсем, а только левые функции советует!

[image: не показывает функции в файле]

Как это поведение исправить и сделать работу удобной?

Comment: А вы уверены, что задавить абсолютный путь `D:\\Dev\\Project\\js\\storm\\inc.js` - правильно?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko если этот вариант работоспособен, то почему он неправильный?

Comment: Потому что при переносе проекта на другой компьютер или хостинг, у вас не будет такого же пути. И весь проект не будет работать.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, кто-то сказал что он будет переносится? Факт того, что вам что-то кажется, не делает что либо неправильным. В данном случае, был задан вопрос про работу в определенной среде, были представлены примеры, а вы вместо ответа на конкретный вопрос начинаете указывать что верно, а что нет.
Да, абсолютный путь не есть хорошо, но "неправильным" это код не делает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

такие пути в `require()` IDE не поддерживает. В случае, если соответствующий файл лежит в проекте, имя модуля будет ресолвиться просто по имени, и подсказки работать не будут; если файл находится вне папки проекта, модули из него вообще не будут найдены, т.к. файлы вне проекта не индексируются, и никакие функции работы с кодом (кроме базовой синтаксической подсветки) для них не доступны. Поэтому, если хотите, чтобы работа была удобной, положите файл в папку проекта и используйте относительные пути в `require()`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя node.js сам по себе поддерживает загрузку модуля по абсолютнму пути, использование таких путей - это bad practice, т.к. такой код будет работать только на вашей машине

Comment: Это какие такие? Если имеется в виду абсолютные, то вы не правы, абсолютные пути вебшторм понимает, он не понимает "\\" вместо "/". 

Также, помимо копипаста файлов в папку с решением у вебшторма можно добавить индексируемые каталоги, в ответе было бы неплохо увидеть как. 

Дополните  свой ответ чтобы можно было считать его решением.

Comment: При указании только имени файла в require, IDE видит его, но вот только код такой при запуске не работает, а чтобы работал, файл должен лежать в папке "node_modules", относительно выполняемого js файла. Для доступа относительно текущего js файла используется require('./inc.js'), вместо require('inc.js').

Comment: я нигде и не советовала использовать только имя, я писала про относительные пути, т.е. пути, начинающиеся с `./` или `../`. Индексируемые каталоги можно добавить  через *Add content root* в *Settings | Directories*

Comment: после такого добавление шторм видит функции в файле, но предлагает их использовать только после частичного ввода имени, что не является удобным, как это исправить?

Comment: у меня подсказка появляется после точки, вводить имена функций не нужно - см скриншот в моем ответе. Но работает это только в случае, когда путь к модулю корректно распознается, не в случае абсолютных путей в windows формате

Comment: я говорю про вариант с добавлением индексируемых каталогов, про относительный путь и проект в самой папке решения я же уже написал в комментарии выше.
Если добавить через "Add content root в Settings | Directories" новую папку и в require указать абсолютный путь, то подсказки по функциям будут только после частичного ввода функции

Comment: это потому, что такие пути не поддерживаются, и функции ресолвятся просто по имени, как я и писала